# Gradle : Include output JAR of main/java sourceset as a dependency to compile test/java sourceset

Tags: java, ant, gradle

We have an ANT build where, in the **main** sourceset     **javac** compiles certain classes and produces a JAR. This JAR is used in the Classpath while compiling the **test** sourceset of the same project.

How can I replicate this in GRadle. We dont want to use ant.javac command. We are trying to re-write the entire ant script to Gradle. 
How to compile the test classes with a dependency on the output JAR of the main class. (in the same build.gradle)

Comment: Why don't you just do it "the standard way"? By default, test sources will depend on main sources, no need to generate a jar inbetween

Comment: I need to generate a JAR for other purposes. Used by other dependent projects.

Comment: Yes, but in the process you can generate it independently from tests

Comment: `sourceSets {   
        main {   
            java { srcDirs 'csw/src/java'   
            include '**/csw/**/*.java'   
            }  
        test{ java { srcDirs 'csw/test/java' }}}  


task cswJar1(type: Jar) { "Generates JAR" }  
`
So here compiletestJava fails because its compilation depends on the JAR generated by task cswJar1. It says "cannot find symbol" on a method which is actually inside the JAR produced above. How to add the output JAR in compiletestJava dependency ?

Comment: Why isn't `apply plugin: "java"` good enough? What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: My objective is to compile the main sourceset and generate 4 different jars out of it having different combination of .java and their .class files. For this I am using 4 custom jar tasks for 4 different jars.
Next thing is to compile the test sourceset with all these 4 jars in its class path for compilation ? Not sure how to achieve this in Gradle..

Comment: Why not compile and run tests with the output (classes directory) produced by the main source set? That's the default behavior. Otherwise, you'll have to reconfigure both `sourceSets.test.compileClasspath` and `sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath` to instead contain the four Jars.